# Yii checkbocklist + textfield?

Tags: yii

формирую чекбокслист для сохранения связи многие ко многим. но в эту же таблицу хочу прописывать еще одно поле.

имею пока такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вот как в ид textField передать ид текущего чекбокса?

```
<?php
        //данные для элементов    
        $type_list = CHtml::listData(Element::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');

        if (isset($model->id))
        {
            $arr = HasElem::model()->findAll("template_id=:id", array(':id' => $model->id));
        }

        if (isset($arr))
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
            {                    
                $arr_bit[] = $arr[$i]->elem_id;
            }
        }
        else
            $arr_bit = array();

        $data = CHtml::textField('textField'); 
        echo CHtml::checkBoxList('im_id2', $arr_bit, $type_list, array(
            'template' => "{input} {labelTitle} $data",
            'class' => 'chclass',
            'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
                )
        );
        //просто рисуем чекбокслитс из базы
        //данные для элементов
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через checkBoxList так сделать не получится. Предпочтительный вариант, пройтись циклом по массиву $type_list и сгенерировать нужные данные.

Через checkBoxList это можно решить, только если пройтись по списку с помощью JS и заменить нужные ид.

Comment: то есть циклом генерить кучу отдельных чекбоксов?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Реализацию можно позаимствовать в том же checkBoxList.